# Identificar y controlar un filesize 0 - PHP

Tags: php, filesize

tengo un código, el cual recorre un directorio en busca de archivos
Cuando el código encuentra el archivo, lo copia en otro directorio.

El problema que tengo, es que a veces, los archivos vienen vacíos, con peso 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, el archivo viene completamente vacío, pero no logro obtener un filtro o calculo de peso, por que, `filesize` que es el que estaba usando, no obtiene pesos ene este caso...

Ahora mismo, estaba haciendo un reporte automático, en caso de que no logre obtener archivos, entonces, el array que busco, lo comparo al contenido del directorio en donde estoy buscando, y si no lo encuentra, pues ok... pero si tiene peso 0, también lo muestra como no encontrado.
Faltaría poder saber cual es peso 0...

```
foreach ($array as $r) { //Por cada archivo buscado
    if(in_array($r.".xml", $repBackup)){ //Busco el archivo en el directorio
        fwrite($logR, "Encontrado: " . $r . PHP_EOL); //Encontrado
    }else{
        fwrite($logR, "No encontrado: " . $r . PHP_EOL); //No Encontrado
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizá podrías usar la función [stat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.stat.php).

- Creamos un fichero vacío y verificamos el tamaño:

```
-> touch example_file
-> stat -c %s example_file 
0
```

- Hacemos un `var_dump` del resultado teniendo en cuenta que en la documentación vemos que la posición 7 del array resultado de ejecutarlo devuelve el tamaño:

Código:

```
<?php

var_dump(
    stat('example_file')[7]
);
```

Resultado:

```
-> php size.php
int(0)
```

- Añadimos un fichero con datos para que tenga un tamaño distinto a cero:

```
-> echo "Archivo con datos" > example_file_1
-> stat -c %s example_file_1
18
```

Vemos que con `stat` obtiene el mismo dato:

```
-> cat size.php 
<?php

var_dump(
    stat('example_file_1')[7]
);
-> php size.php 
int(18)
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Son puros XML? Qué tal usar [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-file.php) y [SimpleXMLElement::count](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.count.php) para verificar si el XML es válido y tiene al menos un nodo con datos. Tratar de cargar un XML vacío o mal formado arrojará un error, el cual será manejado por [libxml_use_internal_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-errors.php).

```
<?php
// ... 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('mi_archivo.xml');
if ($xml and ($xml->count() > 0)) {
    echo 'XML valido';
    // Procesar ...
} else {
    echo 'Archivo vacio o no valido';
    // Omitir o eliminar ...
}
```

Comment: Es que si son XML los valido en otro momento, pero si no lo son ???

Comment: Y que validas aca ??? `if ($xml and ($xml->count() > 0)`

Comment: Si `simplexml_load_file()` puede leer un objeto xml válido, devuelve un `Objeto XML`;  de lo contrario, `false`. Además (`and`) si el xml tiene al menos un nodo principal con datos u otros subnodos, entonces `count()` será mayor que `0`. Pero un xml puede ser válido con un nodo principal vacío (`count = 0`). Si no te interesa eso, puedes eliminar esa condición `and ($xml->count() > 0)`.